# Product not visible after migration

Tags: magento2

I have migrated from magento 1.9 to magento 2 everything migrated successfully. and i can see products in backend and it is assigned to a category. but when i open category on frontend i dont see any product and also elastic search is running properl.

did anyone face this issue or if i run composer install will it going to fix the issue.
Any help or suggestion will be great.

Comment: First of all run indexer and and clean cache also check product inventory is imported properly or not if you are using latest magento version that is 2.4.x then you should also check your elasticsearch is working perfectly and connected with your magento.

Comment: yes i have already checked that and elastic search is running

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to run following command ?

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Comment: already tried this

Comment: any error in indexing ?